# PHP - lookup array contents with dot syntax

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, smarty

Does anybody see anything wrong with the following function? (**Edit**: no, I don't think anything is wrong, I am just double-checking since this will be inserted into a very common code path.)

```
function getNestedVar(&$context, $name) {
    if (strstr($name, '.') === FALSE) {
        return $context[$name];
    } else {
        $pieces = explode('.', $name, 2);
        return getNestedVar($context[$pieces[0]], $pieces[1]);
    }
}
```

This will essentially convert:

```
$data, "fruits.orange.quantity"
```

into:

```
$data['fruits']['orange']['quantity']
```

For context, this is for a form utility I am building in Smarty.  I need the name for the form also so I need the string to be in a key-based form, and can't directly access the Smarty variable in Smarty.

Comment: no. is there supposed to be something wrong with that function?

Comment: @echo, no, see edit above.  I'm just not sure if I'm missing something totally obvious either why not to do this the way I am, or if there is some much easier way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try an iterative approach:

```
function getNestedVar(&$context, $name) {
    $pieces = explode('.', $name);
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (!is_array($context) || !array_key_exists($piece, $context)) {
            // error occurred
            return null;
        }
        $context = &$context[$piece];
    }
    return $context;
}
```

Comment: I like it... only one use of explode will occur and no strstr checks.  Way less string parsing going on than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/elfet/4713488

```
$dn = new DotNotation(['bar'=>['baz'=>['foo'=>true]]]);

$value = $dn->get('bar.baz.foo'); // $value == true

$dn->set('bar.baz.foo', false); // ['foo'=>false]

$dn->add('bar.baz', ['boo'=>true]); // ['foo'=>false,'boo'=>true]
```

And this class also have PHPUnit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with that code. I've tested it as well.

This is IMHO slightly nicer. It doesn't use recursion, and returns null in case a child of a non-array is accessed.

```
function getNestedVar(array $array, $name) {
   $name = explode('.', $name);
   foreach($name as $namePart) {
      if (is_array($array)) return null;
      if (!isset($array[$name])) return null;
      $array = $array[$name];
   }

   return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In its current form no error/warnings are shown if one or more elements do not exist

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$x = array();
getNestedVar($x, '1.2.3.4');
echo 'done.';
```

(tested with php 5.3.1/win32).
For some reason accessing a non-existing element in `getNestedVar($context[$pieces[0]]...` does not raise a warning message, which makes it really hard to debug and to find e.g. a typo.

Comment: Correct... I just want null returned if it does not exist, as it would with standard array access.

Comment: ...which is fine. I was just baffled that php itself does not raise a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Why you not just make use of html.. `name="fruit[orange]"` is enough.. to make an array.