# php - split string into multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Im trying to split navigation position strings into a master array.

For example, If I have an item that's position is 1.2.2

I would like to add it in the master array as follows

```
 1 =>
    2 =>
        2 => array()
```

And then if another item has '2.1'

```
 1 =>
    2 =>
        2 => array()
 2 =>
    1 => array()
```

and then another '1.2.3'

```
 1 =>
    2 =>
        2 => array()
        3 => array()
 2 =>
    1 => array()
```

does anyone know of a way for doing this?

regards

**edit**

lets say I have a one dimensional array of objectects, I want to loop through them and store as a structured "navigation" like nested array. Each item has a navigation position string, i.e. **1.2.3.6**

I then was thinking of `$depth = explode( '.', $details['navigation_pos'] );` running it through some kind of array walker to place the object in the correct position.

hope this helps

**edit**

maybe a better way to put it is this, but more elegantly:

```
$depth = explode( '.', '1.2.3.4' );
$bar = json_decode( '{"' . implode( '":{"', $depth ) . '":[]' . str_repeat( '}', sizeof( $depth ) ) );
print_r($bar);
```

which would give

```
stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What is your input is it a string or a array and what should be the output ?

Comment: where your array will be stored? in session?

Comment: @Luke Snowden, display your exact string

Comment: not quite sure what your asking... the position string, is a string i.e. '1.2.3' and I want to store a reference of the associated item at that point so I can loop through them and display a nested navigation

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `eval()` construct, but beware:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

```
$final_array = array(); // The output array

/*
    Example:
    $big_array = array(
        '1.1' => 'One-one',
        '2.1.3.4' => 'Two-one-three-four'
    );
*/  

foreach ($big_array as $position_string => $item)
{
    $index_array = explode(".", $position_string);

    foreach ($index_array as $key => $value)
    {       
        // Make sure only integers are put through eval()
        $index_array[$key] = (int)$value;
    }

    $indexes = implode("][", $index_array);

    // TODO: make sure $item is safe to put through eval()!
    eval("\$final_array[{$indexes}] = \$item");
}
```

Comment: hmmm, gonna test the above. Managed to get it to work with the following
`$depth = explode( '.', $details['navigation_pos'] );
$bar = json_decode( '{"' . implode( '":{"', $depth ) . '":{"name" : "' . $details['name'] . '","name" : "' . $details['name'] . '"}' . str_repeat( '}', sizeof( $depth ) ) );
$this->navigation = array_merge_recursive( $this->navigation, (array)$bar );` as well

Comment: You could also try to adapt the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286706/php-lookup-array-contents-with-dot-syntax (so that it sets the value rather than getting it)

Comment: Good solution Luke, I had the same situation. well done and thanks!